# Unable to find sqlite database after publish .Net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-16.04, asp.net-core-2.0

I developed an .NET core MVC app running on Raspberr, 
but when I publish it for Ubuntu Mate,

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r ubuntu.16.04-arm
```

I can't find my sqlite Database although I have set datasource like this:

```
"Data Source=database.sqlite;"
```

The app works fine and comunicates with the database.
Is it correct or am I wrong anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reply to my question in order to help who will have the same doubts.
When I publish in Release the database isn't created, but only when I run the app in the Raspberry for the first time.
Then if I watch in the root of my folder, I can see my Database.sqlite

I hope it can helps.